# Sim not supported on unlocked device

Tags: iphone, activation-lock

I have an Apple iPhone 6 A1586 from the US which was a replacement device from Apple, but the previous handset would've been locked to TMobile (always GSM and never CDMA I believe).

I've inserted a new UK (GSM) SIM into the device and it's telling me the SIM is unsupported. I've checked https://www.icloud.com/activationlock/ and this tells me the device is not locked and can be activated by a new user but I'm unable to do that.

I've wiped the phone and attempted to set it up as a new device but as soon as that new SIM goes into the phone it locks up saying "SIM not supported" but it will still work when I put the old TMobile SIM into it.

Any ideas? Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

You might need the carrier to unlock the device.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201328

Activation Lock in iCloud is to protect the owner of the device from theft.

SIM Lock protects the carrier revenue stream as far as I can tell. Maybe there's another legitimate use for it that I haven't considered.

Comment: Thanks! The phone was a replacement directly from the Apple store so I didn't think it would be locked but when on the phone with TMobile I asked and they said the device was unlocked. I suppose it's worth asking again given the messages I'm receiving?

Comment: Normally, when a repair phone is entered Apple transfers the lock status correctly. You can verify this by restoring the device in iTunes, @Beerlol . It will say device unlocked. In your specific case - if you restore the phone and it's not unlocked and the carrier says it should be unlocked - your first call would be to AppleCare support to have them re-do the process to move the unlock from the old Serial#/IMEI to the replacement Serial#/IMEI